# returning just 'value' of object, not the key?

Tags: javascript

So I have an object (EDIT: originally called it a "hash") like

```
newHash = 
{item1: "spam",
item2: "everything"
}
```

and I want to return just "spam" and "everything".

It seems it doesn't work to write a for loop like this:

```
for (var x in newHash) {return newHash[x].value}
```

Thanks!

EDIT : replaced the word "hash" in question with "Object" as per popular convention.

Comment: "Return" in what format? You can't return multiple values (coming soon to ES6 via destructuring, or perhaps iterators in your case), so what are you looking for? An array of values?

Comment: You shouldnt need the .value part in js, but you presumably will just get the value for the first item in that object, i.e. "spam". youll want to put them in an array or something then return the lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the title of your question, I guess you want to do this :

```
var newHash = {
    item1: "spam",
    item2: "everything"
};
newHash.item1; // "spam"
newHash['item1']; // "spam"
newHash.item2; // "everything"
newHash['item2']; // "everything"
```

Then, if you want to get all the values, you'll need to store them into a list :

```
var list = [];
for (var key in newHash) {
    list.push(newHash[key]);
}
list; // ["spam", "everything"]
list.join(); // "spam,everything"
```

Since your keys are based on the same pattern, you could also do it like so :

```
var list = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    list.push(newHash['item' + i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
function getObjectValues(obj) {
    var i, ret = [];
    for( i in obj) if( obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) ret.push(obj[i]);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#values) (which is a great library!), you can do this:

```
newHash = {
    item1: "spam",
    item2: "everything"
}

_.values(newHash)
```

returns:

```
["spam", "everything"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
return Object.keys(newHash).map(function (key) { return newHash[key]; });
```

,which returns an array with the values in the object.

It works like this: you get an array of keys, then use the map function to get a corresponding array with the value for each key.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

Your object declaration has a " character to much.

```
newHash = {
  item1: "spam",
  item2: "everything"
}

for( var x in newHash )
 console.log(newHash[x]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/upHyu/

Comment: The `"` character is most likely just a typo in the question. This doesn't answer the part about "returning" the values.

Comment: True - I guess I lost focus on that he said the loop did not work.

Answer (score 0):

(function(o){var res=[],i;for(i in o){res.push(o[i]);}return res;})(newHash);

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a values function to the object prototype along the same lines as `Object.keys()`.

```
if (!('values' in Object.prototype)) {
  Object.prototype.values = function (obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function (p) { return obj[p]; });
  }
}

var obj = {
  '1': 'one',
  '2': 'two',
  '3': 'three'
}

console.log(obj.values()); // ["one", "two", "three"]
```